# PMD violation on for each loop (final or not?)

Tags: java, foreach, final, pmd

I just recently found out about PMD and want to improve my code with it. Therefore I have enabled all rules (and got 47000 violations :P). Anyway, I have a problem with this one:

```
double mean = 0;
for (int p : points)
  mean += full[1][p];
mean /= points.size();
```

On the `for each` loop, PMD tells me that ***Local variable 'p' could be declared final***. If I change it to

```
double mean = 0;
for (final int p : points)
  mean += full[1][p];
mean /= points.size();
```

it tells me to ***Avoid using final local variables, turn them into fields***. The second violation doesn't really make sense to me. What is the "correct" way to do this? (I realize that there may be different ways, I just want to know how PMD would like it to be.)

Comment: This looks like a bug in pmd the rules to me.

Comment: Just out of curiosity - how would you increment (or change) a final counter in a loop? ;)

Comment: I am using the PMD eclipse plugin (`PMD Plug-in 4.0.0.v20130510-1000`).

Comment: @Andreas_D Well, I don't in this case, it's a foreach loop. (And the added `final` does work).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight So you think the second code sample is the better one and the second violation is a bug?

Comment: @brimborium - ah, ok, a quick search on SO explained, why it works ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911167/how-does-final-int-i-work-inside-of-a-java-for-loop/3911177#3911177

Comment: I think the first loop is fine as is: the second loop works fine, but using `final` there is so unorthodox, that it could trip even experienced developers (check out the conversation in the comments above for a good example). You do not want to make reading your program any harder than it is, so unless you must have a `final` there for other purposes, such as making the variable available to an anonymous class, I'd recommend skipping the `final`.

Comment: Conclusion: not all PMD rules should be followed! ;-)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thanks for that assessment. If you put that in an answer, I'll accept it. ;)

Comment: @assylias or at least not in all cases. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you found an inconsistency in pmd's rules, when following one of the rules makes you violate another rule.

I think the first loop is fine as is: the second loop works fine, too, but using `final` there is rather unorthodox. Adding a `final` there without a good cause<sup>+</sup> could trip up even very experienced developers. Since you do not want to make reading your program any harder than it is, I'd recommend skipping the `final` in `foreach` loops.

---

<sup>+</sup> Making the loop variable available to an anonymous class is one such good cause.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the final keyword inside the for loop.  This is will prevent people from reassigning the loop variable.

To work around "Avoid using final local variables, turn them into fields" on

`double vStd = 0;` , given that you have not reassigned its value, you can declare this as class constant instead.

In addition, please declare each variable on its own line:

```
double vStd = 0;
double mean = 0;
```

Comment: I get the ***Avoid using final local variables, turn them into fields*** on the `for (final int p : points)` and not on `vStd`. So that won't work. And if I remove the `final` classifier, PMD goes back to the ***Local variable 'p' could be declared final***.

Comment: Thank you for the *one declaration per line* comment, I usually follow this rule. In this case I just wanted to keep the code compact for SO.

Comment: I removed the `vStd` from the example as it has no role in it. ;)

Comment: That is strange, I am not getting that flag on my IDE with your code. I have that rule enabled.  I use eclipse Indigo SR2 with eclipse-pmd plugin v0.8.0.201401251911 and it uses PMD 5.0.5.

Comment: Ah, so maybe it got fixed. My post is nearly a year ago now... And I don't have that setup anymore.