# Cannot refer to a non-final variable l inside an inner class defined in a different method

Tags: android, iteration, onclicklistener

I'm trying to set an `OnClickListener` to some elements in my Android app, these elements are dynamically defined and are not given `id`s, but they are put in a `LinearLayouts` which exists in an `List` of `LinearLayouts`, so I set the `OnClickListener` as follows:

```
    List<LinearLayout> inner_ver = setElemets(1);

       for (LinearLayout l: inner_ver){
                l.getChildAt(0).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { // here's the syntax error
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    l.getChildAt(1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.home_curtopen);
                }
            });
        }
```

but I got the syntax error mentioned in the title with `l` and I can't just declare it as `final` cause then it assigns the changes only to the last element in the `List`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split into a separate method:

```
    for (LinearLayout l: inner_ver){
        assignListener(l);
    }

public void assignListener(final LinearLayout l) {
    l.getChildAt(0).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            l.getChildAt(1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.home_curtopen);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: it's also just deals with the last Layout in the List

Comment: That doesnt seem right. Is it possible you have an error elsewhere in your code? The layout L is scoped to every iteration in the loop seperately.

Comment: you are right, i had also another error but after correcting it your way worked fine with me

Answer (score 3):

You could also create your own OnClickListener class:

```
class MyOnClickListener implements OnClickListener{
    private LinearLayout layout;

    public MyOnClickListener(LinearLayout layout){
        this.layout = layout;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        layout.getChildAt(1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.home_curtopen);
    }

}
```

Then change your loop to:

```
for (LinearLayout l: inner_ver){
    l.getChildAt(0).setOnClickListener(new MyOnClickListener(l));
}
```

Comment: your way worked also , i just voted it up and choose the "oldest" right answer

Answer (score 1):

You could add `final` to your for loop

```
List<LinearLayout> inner_ver = setElemets(1);

   for (final LinearLayout l: inner_ver){
            l.getChildAt(0).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { // here's the syntax error
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                l.getChildAt(1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.home_curtopen);
            }
        });
    }
```

Why `for(final Type name : Iterable)` works is explained in

[How does "final int i" work inside of a Java for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911167/how-does-final-int-i-work-inside-of-a-java-for-loop)

Comment: He said this still only assigned click to the final loop iteration, but given he didn't like my answer either, I think yours is correct and he has a logic error elsewhere in his code.

Comment: @GregEnnis most likely. `l.getChildAt(0)` could simply be the same thing all the time.

Comment: you point is right too ,but  i just voted it up and choose the "oldest" right answer as an accepted answer

Comment: @MRefaat That's fine. The one you accepted is also a bit cleaner in style since it increases legibility.